# Pular arquivo ao entrar em alguma Exception

Tags: java, exceção, try-catch, scanner

Boa tarde

Abaixo, um método que uso para ler determinados arquivos de uma pasta. O problema é o seguinte. Caso a pasta tenha 50 arquivos(ou 60, ou 70, ou 80 ...) e o método estiver lendo um arquivo "defeituoso"(um dos arquivos que caiam nas `Exeception`), o método trava nesse arquivo e não consome os outros. Gostaria que ao entrar numa `exception`, o fluxo continuasse, e depois voltasse nesse arquivo. Caso estivesse OK, consome, caso não, pula novamente para os outros.

```
public static String lerPasta() throws FileNotFoundException{
      String texto = null;  
        try{    
            FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.getName().endsWith(".XML");
                }
            };
            File dir = new File(diretorioIn);
               File[] files = dir.listFiles(filter);

            for(i = 0; i < files.length ; i++){
                Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(files[i].toString()), "UTF-8");
                texto = s.useDelimiter("\\A").next();     
                System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+"VALOR DE I" +i);
                verificaTipoXML(files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length()));
                System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+" verificaTipoXML:files[i].toString(): "+files[i].toString());
                System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+" lerPasta():" + files[i].toString());
                System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+" verificaTipoXML():" + files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length()+0));
                deleta = files[i].toString();
                //+1
                deleta2 = files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length());
                deletar = files[i];
                System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+" deleta:"+deleta2);
                nomegerado = files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length()+3);
                System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+" GLOBAL:nomegerado:" + nomegerado);
                s.close();
             }

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                 System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+"lerPasta():ERRO: FileNotFoundException : Tentando novamente ...");
        }    
        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
             System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+"lerPasta():ERRO: NoSuchElementException : Tentando novamente ...");

        }
        return texto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu método está travando porque o seu try/catch está fora do for e quando uma exceção é lançada, o laço é interrompido. Basta você mover o try/catch para dentro do for e ele tentará ler todos os arquivos.

Para que ele tente novamente ler os arquivos que falharem, você pode armazená-los numa lista e depois de tentar lê-los novamente. Seria algo assim:

```
public static String lerPasta() {

    FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.getName().endsWith(".pdf");
        }
    };

    File dir = new File(FILE_PATH);
    Iterator<File> files = Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles(filter)).iterator(); 
    List<File> failedFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    while(files.hasNext()) {
        File file = files.next();
        try(Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(file.toString()), "UTF-8")) {
            //Faça o que quiser aqui
            //...
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | NoSuchElementException e) {
            if(failedFiles != null) {
                failedFiles.add(file);
            }
        } finally {
            if(!files.hasNext() && failedFiles != null && !failedFiles.isEmpty()) {
                files = failedFiles.iterator();
                failedFiles = null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Lembre-se de colocar um controle de quantas vezes vai tentar ler os arquivos que falharam pra não ficar em looping tentando ler um arquivo falho.

Comment: @GabrielWeber, o algoritmo só tentará ler os arquivos que falharem uma vez, já que quando eles começam a ser lidos novamente é atribuído `null` a lista de arquivos falhos e mais nenhum elemento é atribuído a ela. Mas sim, caso se queira ter um maior controle sobre o número de tentativas, seriam necessárias alguns adições ao algoritmo.

Comment: é verdade, tens razão! Ficou muito elegante essa sua solução, muito bem.

Answer (score 0):

Ele vai travar porque o for está dentro do try-catch, assim que a exceção for lançada(`FileNotFoundException` ou `NoSuchElementException` ), ele vai sair do for e entrar no catch.

Tenta fazer isso daí. Eu tirei o for de dentro do catch, e coloquei um outro dentro dele(do for). Esse try-catch dentro do for que vai ignorar os arquivos "defeituosos".

Só pra lembrar, não é legal ficar usando try-catch puro, ou seja, escondendo exceção, o motivo tem que ser muito bom.

```
public static String lerPasta() throws FileNotFoundException{
      String texto = null; 
      File[] files = null;    
        try{    
            FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.getName().endsWith(".XML");
                }
            };
            File dir = new File(diretorioIn);
               File[] files = dir.listFiles(filter);

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                 System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+"lerPasta():ERRO: FileNotFoundException : Tentando novamente ...");
        }    
        catch(NoSuchElementException e){
             System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+"lerPasta():ERRO: NoSuchElementException : Tentando novamente ...");
        }

        if(files == null){
            //Lança algum erro.
        }

        for(i = 0; i < files.length ; i++){
            try{
                Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(files[i].toString()), "UTF-8");
                texto = s.useDelimiter("\\A").next();     
                System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+"VALOR DE I" +i);
                verificaTipoXML(files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length()));
                System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+" verificaTipoXML:files[i].toString(): "+files[i].toString());
                System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+" lerPasta():" + files[i].toString());
                System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+" verificaTipoXML():" + files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length()+0));
                deleta = files[i].toString();
                //+1
                deleta2 = files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length());
                deletar = files[i];
                System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+" deleta:"+deleta2);
                nomegerado = files[i].toString().substring(diretorioIn.length()+3);
                System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(fusoHorarioDeSaoPaulo)+" GLOBAL:nomegerado:" + nomegerado);
            }catch(AlgumaException e){
                //Não faz nada.
            }finally{
                s.close();
            }
        }
    return texto;
}
```